# How to get GCM notification messages into an activity in android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Explanation:
           I am using GCM to send notification to the users.Everything is completed.I was created a server side programming to create a rest for push_message and all the thing is done.

When i click on the notification this messages are open into my activity.

How can i do to open my messages in my activity?

Here is my GCMIntentService.java

```
package com.angelnx.angelnx.mygcm.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.angelnx.angelnx.mygcm.R;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.mygcm.app.Config;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.mygcm.app.EndPoints;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.mygcm.app.MyApplication;
import com.angelnx.angelnx.mygcm.model.User;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{

    private static final String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }
    public static final String KEY = "key";
    public static final String TOPIC = "topic";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBE = "subscribe";
    public static final String UNSUBSCRIBE = "unsubscribe";

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String key = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
        switch (key) {
            case SUBSCRIBE:
                // subscribe to a topic
                String topic = intent.getStringExtra(TOPIC);
                subscribeToTopic(topic);
                break;
            case UNSUBSCRIBE:
                break;
            default:
                // if key is specified, register with GCM
                registerGCM();
        }

    }
    private void registerGCM(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try{
            InstanceID instanceID=InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token=instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,null);
            Log.e(TAG,"GCM Registration Token:"+token);

            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER,true).apply();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG,"FAILED TO COMPLETED TASK"+e);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER,false).apply();
        }
        //Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(final String token) {

        User user= MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser();

        if(user==null){
            return;
        }
        String endPoint= EndPoints.USER.replace("_ID_",user.getId());
        Log.e(TAG,"endpoints :"+endPoint);

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
                endPoint, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                    // check for error
                    if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                        // broadcasting token sent to server
                        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(Config.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to send gcm registration id to our sever. " + obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                Log.e(TAG, "Volley error: " + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("gcm_registration_id", token);

                Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

    }
    /**
     * Subscribe to a topic
     */
    public static void subscribeToTopic(String topic) {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = instanceID.getToken(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            if (token != null) {
                pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
                Log.e(TAG, "Subscribed to topic: " + topic);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: gcm registration id is null");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Topic subscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), "Topic subscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribeFromTopic(String topic) {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        String token = null;
        try {
            token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            if (token != null) {
                pubSub.unsubscribe(token, "");
                Log.e(TAG, "Unsubscribed from topic: " + topic);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: gcm registration id is null");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Topic unsubscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Topic subscribe error. Topic: " + topic + ", error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me to solve out.

Comment: do you want to open desired activity on click on notificaiton?

Comment: I think when a notification come you notify to your activity using Localbroadcast receiver. am i right?

Comment: yes i think not sure.because i am fresher in android platform.so i want help

Comment: ok. You just show your activity code where you want show the message.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted is an `IntentService` that registers a device for your server with GCM.

The code you need to receive messages from GCM is here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java#L43-L69

Basically, you need to create your own `GcmListenerService`.

Don't forget to put all your services and receivers into `AndroidManifest.xml`. It should look something like this:

```
    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="your package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->
    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name=".GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

Comment: where i used this class?

Comment: for which purpose i use this class can i remove my own class?

Comment: @MilanGajera checkout this example from google: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Comment: @MilanGajera go through this example and you will understand everything you need to know about GCM and android.

Comment: can you explain me well?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create one service that implements GcmListenerService.

```
public class EMSListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "ems_service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, data);

        Display.log(TAG, "EMS received");

    }
}
```

And when you receive the message you need to broadcast to the activity using `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: i am not understand .